# Use Python create a dictionary and filtering data

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file contains multiple columns like this:

```
> A:      A_index            B:      B_index            C:     C_index        
> 762     0.1210728809       615     0.1196903735       312    0.0341544124
  482     0.3124124          762     0.415734           123    0.412456671

...
```

I hope create a dictionary that A,B,C as the 'Key' and index as the value of each line of A,B,C respectively.

`i.e    0.3124124 for 482, 0.415734 for 762`

Then make a filter that to find the same 'Key' (i.e A:762 is same as B:762) and compare the same 'Key's value, if the value of `B:762 > A:762`, then delete `A:762`, retain `B:762` in the csv file.

I know sounds complex, but really appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: 1. What have you done so far? 2. Have you seen `pandas`?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out [filter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
filter(input_filter, input_data.items())
```

Comment: This doesn't provide a complete answer to the question.

Comment: They you should've asked for clarification in the comments before posting the answer.